# Java - How to deal with null value passed by argument?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I wrote this simple function:

```
private String getOperatorForCardinality(String op)
{
    String operator ="";
    if(op!=null)
    {
        if(op.equals(">="))
        {
            operator = ">=";
        }
        else if (op.equals("<="))
        {
            operator = "<=";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        operator = "empty";
    }

    return operator;
}
```

which returns a string.

In the main program I call this function, when the argument is null the compiler displays the error of NullPointerException.
The reason is pretty clear, but I do not know how to deal with the null value when is passed by argument.

Comment: You may want to use `null`-safe string comparison:  `"string_literal".equals(string_variable);`

Comment: Another option is to not allow `null` to be passed as a parameter, and just let it throw an exception because that's a mistake in the calling code.

Comment: sometimes throwing an exception **is** the correct behavior. it depends on your design and expectations.

Comment: Check the error message again, it should mention the line of code where the nullpointerexception shows up. It can't be in the code you showed. The function is correct.

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible for the code you posted to throw a NPE. The error is somewhere else, or you are not running the code you think you are (ie haven't recompiled etc).

That said, your method can be simplified to:

```
private static List<String> OPS = Arrays.asList("<=", ">=");  // can add more valid ops

private static String getOperatorForCardinality(String op) {
    if (op == null)
        return "empty";
    return OPS.contains(op) ? op : "";
}
```

Or if you don't mind nested ternaries:

```
private static String getOperatorForCardinality(String op) {
    return OPS.contains(op) ? op : op == null ? "empty" : "";
}
```

Less code is usually clearer code, and leaves less places for bugs to lurk.

Comment: This code is not doing the same. OP's code will return "" for any non-null argument that is not ">=" or "<="

Comment: @Sentry quite so. I've beefed up the code accordingly.

Comment: Thx. Didn't want to be picky, but my OCD kicked in ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is called defensive programming and you should do something like:

```
private String getOperatorForCardinality(String op) {
    if(null == op) {
        //return null;
        //throw new NullPointerException("...");
    }
    ....
}
```

You should think about how your method should react, need to return null if parameter is null or throw an exception? Generally you cant be sure a parameter will never be null so you have always to check and take action.

Answer (score 1):

This can't throw a null pointer exception:

```
private String getOperatorForCardinality(String op)
{
    String operator = "";
    if(">=".equals(op))
    {
        operator = ">=";
    }
    else if ("<=".equals(op))
    {
        operator = "<=";
    } else {
        operator = "empty";
    }

    return operator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try opposite

```
if (op==null)
operator = "empty";
```